# Dynamically Created Label and Textbox

Tags: c#

Generating only 1 textbox field and label. my plan is to generate only 4 fields in 1 panel

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    int count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
    label.Location = new Point(10, (25 * count) + 2);
    label.Size = new Size(40, 20);
    label.Top = 4;
    label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    label.Name = "label_" + (count + 1);
    label.Text = "Field " + (count + 1);
    panel3.Controls.Add(label);

    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    count = panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count;
    textbox.Location = new Point(60, 25 * count);
    textbox.Top = 4;
    textbox.Size = new Size(301, 20);
    textbox.Name = "textbox_" + (count + 1);
    textbox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_Changed);
    panel3.Controls.Add(textbox);
}
```

Comment: You should add 3 more textboxes.

Comment: the plan is to generate label and textbox. by clicking the button.

Comment: There are 2 panels here `panel1` and `panel3`? Which one do you want to use?

Comment: panel3 I changed already.

Comment: If you want to create more fields upon further clicks you need to set the positions not in absolute numbers but calculated from the number of controls already there.. You already have calculated `count`, why not use it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop to add more than one textbox and label at the same time and you have to remove `textbox.Top = 4;` because your overwriting `label.Location = new Point(10, (25 * count) + 2);` and all of your controls will have the same position.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int count = 0;count < 4; count++)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Location = new Point(10, (25 * count) + 2);
        label.Size = new Size(40, 20);
        label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        label.Name = "label_" + (count + 1);
        label.Text = "Field " + (count + 1);
        panel3.Controls.Add(label);

        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        textbox.Location = new Point(60, 25 * count);
        textbox.Size = new Size(301, 20);
        textbox.Name = "textbox_" + (count + 1);
        textbox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_Changed);
        panel3.Controls.Add(textbox);
    }        
}
```

If you want to add one textbox and label per click you can declare a field `int count` that counts the number of created control pairs:

```
int count = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Location = new Point(10, (25 * count) + 2);
        label.Size = new Size(40, 20);
        label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        label.Name = "label_" + (count + 1);
        label.Text = "Field " + (count + 1);
        panel3.Controls.Add(label);

        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        textbox.Location = new Point(60, 25 * count);
        textbox.Size = new Size(301, 20);
        textbox.Name = "textbox_" + (count + 1);
        textbox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_Changed);
        panel3.Controls.Add(textbox);
        count++;
}
```

Comment: got on application on break

Comment: Whats the problem? I run the code and had no problems. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: already works but. generated 4 fields. the plan is every button click add one field

Comment: I have added the code for generating one textbox and label per click